# Checks for a Path in a List of Strings Given a Starting and Ending Point

Tags: python, string, search, path, divide-and-conquer

We are tasked to create a program that will check if there is a possible way of going from a starting string to an end string, given a list of strings with the **same** length. There is a catch, **we can only go from the current string to the adjacent string if both strings only have one character that is different**. If there is no possible path from the starting string to the end string, just print `not possible` but if there is, output the number of steps from the start to end.

```
Example:
li = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted"]
start = "roaster"
end = "booster"

Output: 3

li = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coastal", "coasted"]
start = "roaster"
end = "coasted"

Output: none
```

I made an approach which manually checks if adjacent strings only have 1 character differences and returns the result based on these differences. Kinda slow if you ask me, given that the length of the list could be **at most 100**. Can you demonstrate a faster approach?

```
def checker(str1, str2, change = 0):

    for index, character in enumerate(str1):      # Traverses the whole
        if character != str2[index]:              # string and checks for   
            change+=1                             # character differences 
                                                  

    return True if change == 1 else False              # Only 1 character is different

li = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted"]
m = len(li)

for j in range(m): li.append(input())
start, end = input().split()

if end in li: endI = li.index(end)               # Gets end string index in the list
else:
    print("not possible")
    break

if start in li: startI = li.index(start)         # Gets start string index in the list
else:
    print("not possible")
    break

if startI < endI:                                # If start string comes first before 
                                                 # the end string, keep incrementing.

    while li[startI] != end and startI < m-1:

        if not checker(li[startI], li[startI+1]):
            print("not possible")
            break

        startI += 1

    print(abs(startI-(li.index(start)+1)))

else:                                            # Otherwise, keep decrementing.                                             

    while li[startI] != end and startI > 0:

        if not checker(li[startI], li[startI-1]):
            print("not possible")
            break

        startI -= 1

    print(abs(startI-(li.index(start)+1)))
```

If my approach is the fastest (which I highly doubt), I want to know if there are loopholes in my approach. Assume that the start and end strings can also be absent in the list given. Just print `not possible` if they are not in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that looks better:

```
import regex

def word_path(words, start, end):
    if end in words and start in words:
        endI = words.index(end)
        startI = words.index(start)
    else:
        return "not possible"

    step = 1 if startI <= endI else -1

    for index in range(startI, endI, step):
        if not regex.match("(%s){e<=1}" %li[index], li[index + step]):
            return "not possible"
    return abs(startI - endI) + 1

li = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coastal", "coasted"]
start, end = input().split()
print(word_path(li, start, end))
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to be `re` and not `regex`. Anyway, I tried your code but it outputs `not possible` for the input `roaster booster` which is wrong. It should output `3`.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be regex. Regex provides additional regular expression features, e.g. it makes it possible to check for a number of errors {e<=1}. The re- module doesn't provide these features. I guess that is the reason for the wrong result. You may need to install the regex-module with pip install regex first, but then it should work:

[regex_module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVIsm.png)

Comment: That's odd. I am using Thonny and when I use your code, it reports that there is no such module called `regex`.